# Remove Apple Music in the Music App

Tags: macos, music, apple-music, itunes-store, music.app

I have my own music saved in a folder, which I imported into the music app in macOS Monterey. They can be found in this section:

[image]

However, I have a problem. I don't want the Apple music section to be there:

[image]

There is also a iTunes Store header, which I also want removed:

[image]

How can I make it so I only see my own music, and not bothered by all the paid subscriptions Apple offers?

Comment: go to the music menu > Preferences > General and un-check iTunes store. The Apple Music section, not sure if that is removable